# node.js: compare array of ObjectIds with a string object id or an array of string ObjectIds

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My Schema is:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    players: {
        type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId]});
```

I'm using Promises. My simple query to fetch the collection by id is:

```
MyModel.findById(id).exec()
 .then(function (doc) {
            //here I'm getting my doc
        })
        .catch(next)
```

I'm getting my document but the problem is here I'm getting an array of ObjectIds and I want to compare this array of ObjectIds with an ObjectId which I have in the string form. In one case I want to find the index of this string id in that array of ObjectIds.

I tried by **lodash** like

```
var index = _.indexOf(doc.players, idInStringForm);//getting -1 as response
```

also tried with

```
var index = _.indexOf(doc.players.toString().split(","), idInStringForm);//it is working
```

but when I needed to take union of ObjectIds' arrays the above logic fails for example:

```
 var arrayOfIds = _.union(doc.players.toString().split(","), stringArrayOfIds);
```

the above is not working because when doc.players is empty the arryaryOfIds also contains **" "** which fails my one of queries.

**Does we have any better/common solution for the above cases or we need to go with if-else check?**

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out any empty strings before checking the union of the array and the id.

```
function removeEmptyStrings(value) {
  return value != "";
}

array = array.filter(removeEmptyStrings);
```

Wherever the array value is equal to an empty string it will remove it from the array.

See the documentation for the filter method here: [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Why not `Array.prototype.map` and then `union`?

```
_.union(doc.players.map((player) => player._id), stringArrayOfIds)
```